# Rails 2: How to specify web browser version to be used by Selenium Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.17:

```
rspec-rails        1.3.4
selenium-webdriver 2.34.0
```

Now as per selenium webdriver version it should use firefox 3. I have firefox 3 and firefox 31 on my linux system.

I want that selenium should use firefox 3 while running rspec acceptance tests. How can I specify firefox version for selenium in rspec?

NOTE: I can't upgrade above said version of gems. It will not support my rails version.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect selenium just picks up whatever version of firefox it finds on your system. So in order to solve this you could run your tests with different firefoxes in your `PATH`.